# Removing dot (thousands separator) in a numeric apex:inputField

Tags: visualforce, inputfield, formatting

I have one field "MyYear__c" on my custmon object. This field has following details:

Data Type: Number 
Length: 4 
Decimal Places: 0

At the visualforce page it looks like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!obj.MyYear_c}" required="true"/>
```

The user must fill this field out and then the outputPanel is re-rendered. After that there is a dot in this field:

[image]

**Is there a way to remove the dot?** I don't want to use any "not clear" solutions like Javascript. I want to know is there a "native" visualforce or apex solution for that. I know there are some [workrounds](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7468/number-field-without-comma), but only for the `outputText`, not for `inputField`.

Thank you.

---

Here my code:

Page:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="mainBlock">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <apex:inputField value="{!obj.MyNumber__c}" required="true"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Validate" action="{!doValidation}" reRender="mainBlock"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Controller:

```
public MyObject__c obj { get; set; }

public MyClass(){
    obj = new MyObject__c();
}

public PageReference doValidation(){
    // Validation stuff here
    return null;
}
```

Comment: where comma is? I can only see dot.

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: @KevinO'Hara Hey Kevin, i don't think it will help, but i've posted my code (very simplified).

Comment: Shoot. You have me stumped. I've not encountered this before.

Comment: Here's the [idea to support number display formats](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000BrGKAA0).  I think you'd need something like that if you want to use inputField and no JS.

Comment: @PeterKnolle Hi Peter, thank you for the answer. The problem is that this field is shown at the standrad layout page with the dot too. The only solution is to make another formula field and convert the number to the text, but this will not solve the original problem.

Comment: So probably important to note here that you're probably not dealing with English?  With an English locale we'll see a comma, not a dot.  So it's not a decimal point issue, right?

As for removing it, I'm not sure why you've labelled JavaScript as "not clear", but a quick jQuery function would be a fairly simple solution.

Comment: @joshbirk Hey Josh, but how about standard layout page? I don't think i can remove the damned dot with javascript over there.

Comment: Thanks to the constraints on the edit page, not in any way that would be desirable (ie a full override, but that defeats the page layout in general).

Another option would be similar to your formula field solution, but instead of a formula field use a text field and then coordinate the validation and values between the two via workflows/triggers.

So your "public" field would be text, and your value field would be the current one.

Comment: Adding to @joshbirk's idea of using text as the main input...You could use a picklist for the year if the possible values are limited and then use a Number formula for any calculations needed behind the scenes.  This could reduce some validations as well. I think these comments have a lot of reasonable alternatives/answers. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using inputText in your Visualforce?:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!obj.MyNumber__c}" required="true"/>
```

You will need to validate that the text is a number in your controller.

You will also need to [make use of a formula field for standard UIs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/7478/653).

Comment: I will accept this answer as only solution for the "problem", apparently there are no other "native" solutions. Thanks Stephen.